# Why use one dimensional array instead of a two dimensional arrray?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I was doing some work handling a lot of information and my partner told me that I was using too many matrices to manipulate the variables of the problem. The idea was to use one dimension arrays `int a[]` instead of the 2 dimensional arrays `int b[][]`, to save memory and processing speed of the algorithm. How certain is that this change will accelerate the speed of execution or compilation of my code in c ++?

Comment: It should make no difference, if you really are talking about 1D vs. 2D arrays. The data layout is contiguous for both. The 2D array has clever indexing, which you would have to implement by hand when using a 1D array in lieu of a 2D one.

Comment: This change would have no effect on the compilation speed. It does have a potential of reducing the memory footprint, in cases when you allocate `int b[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]` and use only a portion of it.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, there's always something to say for readability too though.  Speed wise, the difference is negligible at best.

Comment: Considering how far compiler-transformations go, you are likely to get the same result for both. Measure and compare, don't theorize without any data. Premature optimization is the root of much evil.

Comment: Actually rectangular 2D arrays, `int b[R][C]`, will end up to be 1D array.

Comment: You can always *treat* the 2D array (if it really is one, i.e. is not a jagged array) as a 1D array, because the Holy Standard guarantees that arrays are contiguous with no padding. This stems from the `sizeof` guarantees. That said, for a 2D array of dynamic size it's usually simplest to implement it in terms of a single 1D array, e.g. use a `std::vector` as storage.

Comment: Note, above advice only applies for non-dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: `and my partner told me that I was using too many matrices to manipulate the variables of the problem.` ... `to save memory and processing speed of the algorithm`  I think you should seriously consider getting a different partner.

Comment: Plain old 2d arrays, no difference. However, sometimes 2d arrays are represented as an array of pointers to arrays. In that case, each row is in a different location in memory and there are extra levels of indirection to reach the data. This can harm performance, as there is poor data locality. A 1d array using an indexing calculation to simulate a 2d array can help that. This is essentially what normal 2d arrays do.

Comment: @user2366842 - Also, if your 2D arrays are truly dynamic, there are ways of creating the data contiguously *and* keep the `[][]` syntax.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048

Answer (score 2):

Your question invites to guesswork, but:

> How certain is that this change will accelerate the speed of execution or compilation of my code in c ++?

Prognosis is **extremely uncertain**. The only proper response is to measure.

*Measuring is knowing*. You can quote me on that.

Comment: "The only proper response is to measure." +1 /// The rest of the answer. +0 /// Downvoters explain?